# Django ORM better way to manipulate django ORM query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

Below are the models:

```
class Seat(models.Model):
    hall = models.ForeignKey(Hall,on_delete=CASCADE)
    type = models.TextField(verbose_name="Seat Type")

class Show(models.Model):
    show_time = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Show Time')
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie,on_delete=CASCADE)
    hall = models.ForeignKey(Hall,on_delete=CASCADE)
    cinema = models.ForeignKey(Cinema,on_delete=CASCADE)

class Booking(models.Model):
    seat = models.ForeignKey(Seat,on_delete=CASCADE)
    show = models.ForeignKey(Show,on_delete=CASCADE)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie,on_delete=CASCADE)
    hall = models.ForeignKey(Hall,on_delete=CASCADE)
    cinema = models.ForeignKey(Cinema,on_delete=CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Username", on_delete=DO_NOTHING) # donothing
```

**Explanation of the models:**

> Multiple Seats in a Hall

> Each Hall hosts multiple Shows

> Each Booking is basically a ticket for a show with a specific seat and a specific show.

**Requirement is to get a queryset that has all seats not present in the bookings table for a specific show.
Basically, get the list of available seats for a show by checking they are not present in the Bookings table**

The SQL query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Seat as S join Show as Sh on S.hall = Sh.hall join Bookings as B on B.show = Sh.id where Sh.id = 1 AND B.seat IS NULL
```

how to convert this to Django ORM:

able to do it like this (is there a better way rather than creating the seat_id_list?):

```
            qs = Seat.objects.filter(hall=hid) #----------------------------------
            show_bookings = Booking.objects.filter(show=spk)
            seat_id_list = []

            for each_booking in show_bookings:
                print(each_booking.seat.id)
                seat_id_list.append(each_booking.seat.id)
            qss = Seat.objects.exclude(id__in = seat_id_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain these `Seat`s with:

```
Seat.objects.filter(hall=hid).exclude(booking__show=spk)
```

This will retrieve all `Seat`s for a given `Hall` object `hid` where there is no `Booking` for a `Show` determined by the `spk` object.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked well.
What does **booking** represent here? it is not a field  in the Seat model neither in the show model?
also the model is called **Booking**.

Comment: @akashdeep: If you define a `ForeignKey`, Django defines a relation in reverse. By default it uses as `related_query_name` the name of the model where you define it in lowercase, so you can access the related bookings in a query with `booking`.